# Data synchronization between MySQL and MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, data-synchronization, tungsten-replicator

I am looking for a way to synchronize my data from MySQL to MongoDB.
I do not want just to replicate my data, I want them to be permanently synchronized. Does anyone know if Tungsten Replicator would do the job ? I can see that it replicates data but what about replicating data automatically when changes are made in MySQL database ?

If not possible would you suggest any other solution to do this ?

Comment: yikes! mongo and mysql store data in completely different ways (documents vs tables). I don't think it's reasonable or desirable to try and do that. I would recommend just creating backups/replicas in whatever DB you're using rather than try to keep two fundamentally different kinds of databases in sync.

Comment: Someone has done this for Postgres, which doesn't answer your question, but might give you an insight into some of the issues: http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/06/mongodb-replication-from-postgres-using.html

Comment: This guy only did replication. What I need is permanent synchronization between my two databases. I think I am going to use triggers on my MySQL database and a message queue. Anyone has a better solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes `Tungsten Replicator` provide real time synchronization between `MySQL` and `Mongodb` however to get your old data replicated you can use other tools like `mongify` to get old data. Best of Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its possible to have data synchronization between `MySQL` and `MongoDB`using **tungsten replicator**.But it has certain limitations where it does not replicate the DDL events.

kindly look into this [link](http://datacharmer.blogspot.in/2013/05/getting-started-with-replication-from.html) to achieve it.