# How can I sync Data from Mongo DB to Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am trying to sync data from Mongo DB Collections to Mysql Database. I tried cognitom -> momy but that doesn't support array. Is there anything other than that?

P.S First time touching Mongo DB. Junior Developer Here. Thanks

Comment: this is the inverse question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699513/862973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an [article](https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/json-to-relational-mapping-with-spark/) the autor has suggested an open source Spark and Hadoop based [solution](https://github.com/pranab/chombo) on github. Hope it works fine for you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @4castle the link is provided, isn't it?!

Comment: Yes it is, but link-only answers can usually be improved by quoting or summarizing what's in the link. I'm just suggesting how to improve your answer.